# Bootstrap modal second time not triggering a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to trigger a function which is form submit function on a shown.bs.modal, but it only triggers first time.

My modal:
[image]

Each one of the listed item is a form. My jQuery code for this is:

```
$('#edit_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    console.log("shown");
    $('#edit_form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(url, data, function (data) {
            $('#edbtn').attr({
                class: 'btn btn-success',
                disabled: 'true',
                value: data
            });
        });

    });
});
```

in console i can see log "shown" only first time it opens. And only first time on clicking button save, it works normally, but second time it redirects to actionurl.php page, that means it is not triggering this function this time since it is not re shown.

note: I have tried $(this).modal().hide().show(); but this does not
reshow the modal or somethng like that.

Comment: Is the form inside the modal added when the modal is opened?

Comment: Yes, it is adden only when it is opened and not only that, it creates (say) n number of forms with same id and names to perform each individual save action. That's why that event listener which created at the on.shown instance of modal, listens only one time.  May be my code is bad :/

Comment: In such cases it is better to have an empty form and dynamically add elements to it, empty and reuse. From event handling point of view it's usually simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form inside your modal is not added dynamically, when you open the modal, simply getting the binding out of the modal opening event should do the trick:

```js
$('#edit_form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('action');
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  $.post(url, data, function(data) {
    $('#edbtn').attr({
      class: 'btn btn-success',
      disabled: 'true',
      value: data
    });
  });
});
```

---

If the form is added when the modal opens, you need to bind on an existing element, like `<body>`:

```js
$('body').on('submit', '#edit_form', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('action');
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  $.post(url, data, function(data) {
    $('#edbtn').attr({
      class: 'btn btn-success',
      disabled: 'true',
      value: data
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: binding an element worked exactly what I wanted, that a lot sir.

Comment: Idk, why you have edited previous solution of binding and element like <body>, but actually that worked for me, since my modal doesn't hide after first click on save button, so I think your edited solution won't work. Or may be i need to add $(this).modal().hide() somewhere to manually trigger hiding, isn't it?

Comment: @DG_, instead of going to official documentation, I trusted a [so] answer stating `submit` doesn't bubble. So I changed it. I checked it now and it does bubble. That's the proper way to do it. Reverted and thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

If your modal creates dynamically (if it deletes from the dom after closing and appends on open) you need to use another event construction:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#edit_modal', function (event) { ... })
```

Same thing for the submit event:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#edit_form', function(event) { ... })
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a new submit listener every time the modal is shown. To prevent attaching multiple listener to a single form:

```
 $('#edit_form').off("submit").on("submit",function (event){
  //blah
  })
```

and in older versions of jquery:

```
 $('#edit_form').unbind("submit").bind("submit",function (event){
  //blah
  })
```

If the form exists before opening the modal, a better way would be to set the listener just once and outside of modal events.

Comment: While this will work in most cases, it's pretty aggressive (it will unbind any functionality added by other functions/plugins on the form) which could lead to subtle (and hard to trace) bugs. It's better to only unbind only what you bound.

Comment: Actually, I'm not setting multiple listener for a single form, infact I'm setting multiple form for a single listener :D,  that's where the problem began. It listens only first time for first form.